upload several image in another folder via Roboflow API upload
I have paid account for my detection project yolov8. I wrote code on python for upload images directly to folders in my project via API and it works well, but sometimes 1 or 2 images upload in new folder with same name (like on pictures). My code work on AWS Cloud via VScode. How i can fix it?I try to fix it with add time.sleep() in different parts of my code, but it not help.
def upload_dataset(i):
batch_name=(f'{str(i)}_24_04_24')
print(batch_name)
workspace = rf.workspace("my_workspace")
workspace.upload_dataset(
project_name="my_project",
dataset_path='/home/ubuntu/images/dataset',
num_workers=25,
project_license="MIT",
project_type="object-detection",
batch_name=batch_name)



This is Tony from Roboflow engineering team. Thank you for the detailed description.
This seems like a racing condition in our backend. I'll file a bug with instructions to come back here after it's resolved.
Meanwhile can you try adding num_workers=1 to workspace.upload_dataset?
    workspace.upload_dataset(
        project_name="my_project",
        dataset_path='/home/ubuntu/images/dataset',
        project_license="MIT",
        project_type="object-detection",
        batch_name=batch_name,
        num_workers=1
    )

This will tell the CLI to upload 1 image at a time (instead of 10 which is the default). It will be slower, but may fix the problem.
